# React Navigation - custom screen navigate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react navigation for navigate screen. I used nested navigation, `TabNavigator` and `StackNavigator`.

As I know when swiping around, the screen are follow by what we set at on `TabNavigator`.

**Normally Screen Followed**

One > Two > Three > Four > Five

**What I need**

One > Two > Four > Five

Reason I skip `Three` is I want this screen is call by `this.props.navigation.navigate('ThreeScreen')` , but I still wanted it on the navigation bar. Is it possible ? or have any other suggestion can do like this ?

```
const mainNav = TabNavigator({
  One: { 
    screen: OneScreen,
  },
  Two: {
   screen: TwoScreen,
  },
  Three: {
   screen: ThreeScreen,
  },
  Four: {
   screen: FourScreen,
  },
  Five: {
   screen: FiveScreen,
  },
} );

export const mainStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: mainNav},
  Content: { screen: ContentScreen },
});
```

Comment: u are saying like u want to navigate to four by skipping three but u want Screen3 on back press right?

Comment: @Vicky yes, you are right

Comment: @Vicky Screen3 is call from `this.props.navigation.navigate('ThreeScreen')`, so it should be overlay

Answer (score -1):

Add `gesturesEnabled` in `navigationOptions` either :

**Inside component**

```
class ThreeScreen extends React.Component {

     static navigationOptions= {
       gesturesEnabled: false
     };

}
```

**Or directly, inside the routing configuration**

```
const mainNav = TabNavigator({
   //....
  Three: {
   screen: ThreeScreen,
   navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false,
   }
  },
 //....

} );
```

Comment: `Three` still able to swipe arround